# C# Conexión con API con Token

Tags: c#, api, rest, tokens, restsharp

Estoy realizando la conexión a una `API REST` desde un proyecto en C# pero no sé el porque no consigo conectar.

La API dispone de un sistema que a las 5 llamadas sin TOKEN aparece este mensaje:

> {\"detail\":\"Solicitud fue regulada (throttled). Expected available
>   in 85856 seconds.\"}

Intento aplicar el Token mediante el Header Authorization y nada no hace nada, lo he intentado de la forma clásica con HTTPClient y con el componente RestSharp.
Añado ejemplos para que me podáis decir o guiar que estoy haciéndo mal y también una captura de pantalla de la llamada mediante POSTMAN que si funciona con el Header Authorization.

**HTTPCLIENT**

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress =  new Uri("https://www.URLWEB.com");            
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                         = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", "{SECRETTOKEN}");

            var result = client.GetAsync("api/urls").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;            

            return result;
```

RESTSHARP

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.URLWEB.com/api");

            var request = new RestRequest("urls", Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Token {SECRETTOKEN}");

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;

            return content;
```

[image: POSTMA: PRUEBA EXITOSA CON TOKEN]

[image: POSTMAN: PRUEBA FALLIDA SIN TOKEN]

A modo de sugerencia de un compañero he probado también el código que genera postman de la llamada existosa que es:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.URLWEB.com/api/urls");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
request.AddHeader("referer", "https://www.URLWEB.com/api/urls");
request.AddHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate");
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "e3492c30-0025-4324-a241-112c1c618bed,0ddf0c91-f8a4-4a23-84bb-82bd4de554d8");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.15.0");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Token {SECRETTOKEN}");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Pero esto tampoco funciona...

He intentado añadir las configuraciones de ssl con este código que no sé si es correcto:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors) { return true; };
```

Pero tampoco funciona... ya no sé que mas probar, además he probado otra API de pruebas hay en la red con protocolo HTTPS y funciona perfectamente.

Añado mas información, la API está creada con python mediante el Framework Django no sé al 100% como esta realizada la autentificación de Token pero he podido probar con un scrip en python la llamada a la API y funciona perfectamente....  añado el código para que podáis verlo.

```
class Urls(object):
    def __init__(self,url,date,score,matchesi):
        self.url = url
        self.date = date
        self.score = score
        self.matchesi = matchesi

import requests
import io
import json

def object_decoder(obj):
    if '__type__' in obj and obj['__type__'] == 'Urls':
        return Urls(obj['url'], obj['date'], obj['score'], obj['matchesi'])
    return obj

url = 'https://www.URLWEB.com/api/api/urls'
resp = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Token {SECRETTOKEN}'})
x = json.loads(resp.text, object_hook=object_decoder)

print x[0]['url']
```

Comment: Me parece que no está muy claro que error te está dando.

Comment: que es lo que no está claro? No puedo concretarlo mas.

Comment: que error te da? bueno, te saca algún error?, o simplemente no hace nada?.

Comment: El error que me devuelve lo he añadido en el texto es este: {\"detail\":\"Solicitud fue regulada (throttled). Expected available in 85856 seconds.\"} y he añadido las capturas de pantalla de la llamada correcta con token por POSTMAN y la incorrecta con el mismo mensaje sin el TOKEN, lo que deduzco es que las llamadas desde código no está cogiendo bien el TOKEN.

Comment: solo como referencia podrias hacer el [tour] y mirar [ask]? siempre aclara en tu pregunta el error puntual ;)

Comment: ¿La url que estás utilizando es con https o solo para el ejemplo?, si es con https, intenta agregar la configuración de  "SecurityProtocolType" en el request

Comment: es que no puedo concretar mas la pregunta, esto es toda la información que tengo tanto de ejemplos de código como respuestas recibidas y es con lo poco que me estoy peleando yo.

Comment: @CamiloBernal si la url es con HTTPS voy a investigar como aplicarlo a RestSharp y comento a ver...

Comment: he añadido esto pero no termina de funcionar: System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

Comment: ¿Seguro la cabecera va así? Normalmente se usa un [estándar](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml). Por ejemplo: `'Authorization', 'Bearer {token}'`. Verifica si la cosa va por allí. Puedes leer también en [Esquemas de autenticación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Esquemas_de_autenticaci%C3%B3n). Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras si la cabecera funciona así fíjate que la llamada de postman funciona bien, he probado con indicando Bearer {token} pero nada.....

Comment: "throttled" es un mecanismo para control de "alto tráfico", un humano no está abriendo peticiones al servidor constamente. Tú mismo declaras que: "La API dispone de un sistema que a las 5 llamadas..."  Por curiosidad, ¿en qué rango de tiempo realizas cada llamada al servidor? Quizás tengas que esperar más. Si están usando "throttling" y careces de poder para modificar algo en dicha API, dudo que puedas hacer algo diferente a esperar. Saludos

Comment: Para dejar en claro, el "throttling" lo utilizan para disminuir la cantidad de peticiones al servidor. Hay servicios que te dan gratis X llamadas al servidor por minuto/hora/día. Es efecto de mantener a los servidores libres de saturación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una semana después y gracias a varios de vuestros consejos he conseguido encontrar la solución y era una tontería como una casa os lo enseño:

```
var request = new RestRequest("api/urls/", Method.GET);
```

En la dirección del resource que le indicaba al request no añadía una / al final esto
provocaba una re-dirección de api/urls a api/urls/ y como consecuencia hacer que la funcionalidad no se ejecute correctamente.

Muchas gracias por las propuestas han sido muy útiles para el aprendizaje y para tener en cuenta ciertos aspectos que alomejor no tenía.

Comment: ¡Excelente! :D a seguir desarrollando con todo el power 2.0!!!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con WebRequest

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

string url = "https://www.URLWEB.com";
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.Headers["Token"] = "SECRETTOKEN";
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
 if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
 {
  //deserializa el objeto json

 }
```

Comment: Hola! Este código devuelve una excepción que és: ` {"The remote server returned an error: (429) Too Many Requests."} `

Comment: ese error es posiblemente porque has intentado varias veces la solicitud en un corto periodo de tiempo y el servidor piensa que es spamming.

Comment: Ese error me lo devuelve la api cuando la llamo sin el token, lo sé porque desde postman también lo hace, las 5 primeras llamadas sin token funcionan a partir de ahí devuelve este mensaje... Ahí está mi problema.. No coje bien el token.

Comment: Revisa el comentario que dejé en la pregunta.

Comment: @fredyfx muchas gracias por tu comentario lo hemos tenido en cuenta y hemos revisado esa parte, no obstante no era el problema que nos afectaba sino otro.